# mongo sharding across multiple machines connection possible through identity file (.pem)

Tags: mongodb, sharding, pem

Some example illustrating mongo sharding across multiple machines .connection among them is possible through identity file (.pem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable [`--keyFile` authentication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-RunninginSecureMode%28with%5Cauthor%5CkeyFile%29) for your mongod/mongos servers, using your .pem file as the `--keyFile` value.

Note that use of `--keyFile` also enables the general "secure mode" requiring authentication for all user and application connections.

Comment: Thanks Stennie for your answer .This helps me and clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1):

use of --keyFile will accomplish connection across ssh-secured machines.

Generate .pub file from ssh-keygen
`ssh-keygen`

Now you can use that to make mongo interactions
for eg. connectToMongo.pub is my keyfile

`mongod --rest --configsvr --dbpath path --keyFile connectToMongo.pub --port port_number`

`mongod --rest --shardsvr --replSet replica_name  --dbpath path --keyFile connectToMongo.pub --port port_number`

`mongos --configdb ip:port_number --keyFile connectToMongo.pub --port port_number`